# How to call a PHP script with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega, wifi

I have Arduino Mega and ESP-12F module.
Via AT commands I am on my wifi.

Now, I need to call my script on my pages.
Can you tell me how?
This command can conenct to my pages:
Serial3.print("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\"www.artware.cz\",80\r\n");
But that's all, I am not able to call the script.

Sorry, if this is dumb question.
Thank you

Comment: there are 'WiFi' libraries which handle the esp8266 AT commnands for you and have an example for GET request. WiFiEsp library or my WiFiEspAT (the second only if the AT firmware is 1.7 (SDK 3) and you don't need SSL (https))

Comment: Which library do you recommend?

Comment: my WiFiEspAT, if you can flash the AT firmware 1.7 (SDK 3) and you don't need SSL (https) https://github.com/jandrassy/WiFiEspAT

Comment: Do you know which HTTP method the PHP script accepts ? It will be either GET or PUT. If it is the GET method you should be able to simply test it by issuing a command such as www.artware.cz/myApp.php?par1=52 etc. The next step is to issue that URL from your ESP-12 (somehow) and maybe parsing the results.